# ReportViewer - access subreport/drillthough in serverside asp.net

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

When using the ReportViewer control in an aspx page. If you fire an event (such as clicking a row) which then displays a sub/drillthough report...How can you access that Report object on the server side?

There is a DrillThough event for the parent report object that gets fired...but it doesn't seem to have any access to the new report OR what values are being passed to the sub/drillthrough report.

Further, when the page reloads (postback) and the sub-report is displayed, I'm not even sure how to access the sub/drillthrough report during the page_load event...as you can't seem to access it through the parent reportviewer...

I'm using the 2008 ReportViewer object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to access the report using the `DrillThroughEventArgs` in the Report Controls `DrillThrough` event...